# Firebase - send email on order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my firebase application, when user insert a order (child node "orders"), I need to send a confirmation email.

Is possible with firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the easiest way is to use 3rd party service such as SendGrid or MailGun to do this.  You will setup a trigger like this:

```
exports.ordersChanged = functions.database
.ref('/orders/{userID}/{orderID}')
.onWrite(event => {(event => {
     const userID = event.params.userID;
    /* Code to fetch user's email address and send email request to user */
});
```

This trigger will fire for create, update, and delete on that node, so you might want to use the `onCreate` method if you only need this when you initially write the order to the database at this path.

Also, you cannot make requests to 3rd party services with the basic Firebase account so you will need to upgrade your account.